# How can I solve this error?(python crawling)

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have been crawling Flickr data for 2 weeks.
Crawling has been done well.
But, today executing the python code in Windows PowerShell, this error happened.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "getdata_tag.py", line 3 in module
nsid= info["owner"]["nsid"]; 
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

how can I modify this code?
I will add the code here
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: Can you try to print out info.__dict__ in your debug console and see what's dumped onto your console? It should give you a clue on how to proceed. It seems like you're not unpacking the object returned by the flickr api properly

Answer (score 0):

This looks like `info["owner"]` or `info` itself is string, not dictionary.

You must check which scenario is it and then remove `["owner"]["nsid"]` if `info` is string or only `["nsid"]` if info["owner"] is string.

Comment: Thanks. but.. I have to use the "nsid" in the code, so cannot remove it. Could you check the code I attached? How can I modify this code..?

Comment: Problem is that I don't know what is under "info" variable... I only know that trying to treating it or  info["owner"]  as dictionary is causing error. Lack of information.